# How to make the horizontal axis of a chart show dates

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to plot my data on a line chart, and I expect it to show dates on the horizontal axis, i used index_col to set the index as date but that returns an empty dataframe..  can some one help please

```
data = pd.read_csv('good_btc_dataset.csv', warn_bad_lines= True, 
index_col= ['date'])

data.dropna(inplace=True)
data.index = range(3169)
data.head()
```

I expect my chart to show dates on the horizontal axis but all it shows is numbers 
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the plot as well? You could try adding `parse_dates=['date']` and possibly `dayfirst=True` to `read_csv`. Once you have a datetime index, plotting with dates should work. Check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331512/plotting-data-of-a-mysql-database-by-date/56333128#56333128).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to check this script ([it is a copy and paste from the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html)). I think you just need to adapt your own data.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

# Load a numpy structured array from yahoo csv data with fields date, open,
# close, volume, adj_close from the mpl-data/example directory.  This array
# stores the date as an np.datetime64 with a day unit ('D') in the 'date'
# column.
with cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npz') as datafile:
    data = np.load(datafile)['price_data']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('date', 'adj_close', data=data)

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

# round to nearest years.
datemin = np.datetime64(data['date'][0], 'Y')
datemax = np.datetime64(data['date'][-1], 'Y') + np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

# format the coords message box
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = lambda x: '$%1.2f' % x  # format the price.
ax.grid(True)

# rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the
# axes up to make room for them
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks so much it worked. now i have date as index and I am looking for a way to slice data by date .. can you help?

Comment: Thank you BorjaP I sorted the other question to.. I really appreciate

Comment: I would use pandas to filter: for example --> df.loc['2014-01-01':'2014-02-01'] and then make the plot